# Angular 9 String Interpolation with Special Characters / Umlauts

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Hi I am working on a small webapp for a german business and facing the problem that special characters are not rendered correctly.

The meta charset is set to utf8 and I face no problem when having ü ä ö ß in the html itself but when using string interpolation I have the problem.

Here an example: `<span>{{user.lastName}} Müller</span>` :

```
MÃ¼ller Müller
```

I saw people coming up with a workaround to use a pipe and render it as `[innerHtml]` but I am also using it inside of `<input>` and other non html related locations.

Is there no nice way to render these strings properly?

Comment: I dont face that problem... Have you tried logging the user.lastname to the console to see what it looks like there?

Comment: Oh I see. When logging it also says MÃ¼ller but in my database it is correct. Could be the cause that I am reasind the nameit from localStorage?

Comment: I would guess that somewhere on the way from the database to your angular the encoding is different or something like that... Maybe the database stores it in ANSI. Try logging the value on every step and see where it breaks

Comment: Thankyou. I guess I already found the problem. I send the user information with the jwt. I think there is where the encoding of the payload leads to the problem. Do you have an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I got it fixed by decoding the jwt with the npm package `jwt_decode` instead of atob + JSON.parse. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use NGX Translate service. NGX-Translate is an internationalization library for Angular. It lets you define translations for your content in different languages and switch between them easily.

Please find below links for more inforamtion
[ngx-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core)

[Github link](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       template: `
       <div>
        <span>{{name | translate }} Müller</span>
      </div>`,
     })
    export class AppComponent {
       name= 'MÃ¼ller'
       constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
      }
     }
```